# Trying to generate spheres

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to generate spheres within my gameworld.

I have this script: RandomEnvironment

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RandomEnvironment : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Material[] meshMaterials;

    int numberOfMeshes = 50;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfMeshes; i++)
        {
            GameObject planetObject = new GameObject("Planet" + i);
            Randomize randomPlanet = planetObject.AddComponent<Randomize>();
            planetObject.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1000, 1000), Random.Range(-1000, 1000), Random.Range(-1000, 1000));
        }

    }

}
```

And then I have the script Randomize:

```
//http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ProceduralPrimitives

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Randomize : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        MeshFilter filter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        Mesh mesh = filter.mesh;
        mesh.Clear();

        float radius = 1f;
        // Longitude |||
        int nbLong = 24;
        // Latitude ---
        int nbLat = 16;

        #region Vertices
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(nbLong + 1) * nbLat + 2];
        float _pi = Mathf.PI;
        float _2pi = _pi * 2f;

        vertices[0] = Vector3.up * radius;
        for (int lat = 0; lat < nbLat; lat++)
        {
            float a1 = _pi * (float)(lat + 1) / (nbLat + 1);
            float sin1 = Mathf.Sin(a1);
            float cos1 = Mathf.Cos(a1);

            for (int lon = 0; lon <= nbLong; lon++)
            {
                float a2 = _2pi * (float)(lon == nbLong ? 0 : lon) / nbLong;
                float sin2 = Mathf.Sin(a2);
                float cos2 = Mathf.Cos(a2);

                vertices[lon + lat * (nbLong + 1) + 1] = new Vector3(sin1 * cos2, cos1, sin1 * sin2) * radius;
            }
        }
        vertices[vertices.Length - 1] = Vector3.up * -radius;
        #endregion

        #region Normales        
        Vector3[] normales = new Vector3[vertices.Length];
        for (int n = 0; n < vertices.Length; n++)
            normales[n] = vertices[n].normalized;
        #endregion

        #region UVs
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        uvs[0] = Vector2.up;
        uvs[uvs.Length - 1] = Vector2.zero;
        for (int lat = 0; lat < nbLat; lat++)
            for (int lon = 0; lon <= nbLong; lon++)
                uvs[lon + lat * (nbLong + 1) + 1] = new Vector2((float)lon / nbLong, 1f - (float)(lat + 1) / (nbLat + 1));
        #endregion

        #region Triangles
        int nbFaces = vertices.Length;
        int nbTriangles = nbFaces * 2;
        int nbIndexes = nbTriangles * 3;
        int[] triangles = new int[nbIndexes];

        //Top Cap
        int i = 0;
        for (int lon = 0; lon < nbLong; lon++)
        {
            triangles[i++] = lon + 2;
            triangles[i++] = lon + 1;
            triangles[i++] = 0;
        }

        //Middle
        for (int lat = 0; lat < nbLat - 1; lat++)
        {
            for (int lon = 0; lon < nbLong; lon++)
            {
                int current = lon + lat * (nbLong + 1) + 1;
                int next = current + nbLong + 1;

                triangles[i++] = current;
                triangles[i++] = current + 1;
                triangles[i++] = next + 1;

                triangles[i++] = current;
                triangles[i++] = next + 1;
                triangles[i++] = next;
            }
        }

        //Bottom Cap
        for (int lon = 0; lon < nbLong; lon++)
        {
            triangles[i++] = vertices.Length - 1;
            triangles[i++] = vertices.Length - (lon + 2) - 1;
            triangles[i++] = vertices.Length - (lon + 1) - 1;
        }
        #endregion

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.normals = normales;
        mesh.uv = uvs;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.Optimize();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I found the script to generate a sphere on the internet. The Randomize script is supposed to draw me a sphere, and the RandomEnvironment is supposed to make use of that. When I launch the game, I do not get any errors, but there aren't any spheres either. I placed the RandomEnvironment script on an empty gameobject.

I am a beginner with Unity, any help is welcome!

Comment: Well let's start doing this one thing at a time, I'd recommend adding some Debug.Log() at intervals in your program to see what is or isn't getting called at this point.

Comment: ahh, I found an error but it dissapears as soon as I launch it and never reappears

The variable `randomPlanet' is assigned but its value is never used
It did Debug.log("Hello") in the RandomEnvironment script and it logged 50x

Comment: Try renaming the `void start()` function in randomize to `public void Generate()`, then in the RandomEviroment class, after `Randomize randomPlanet = ...` put `randomPlanet.Generate();` and see if that does anything.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I did as you asked and it gives 2 new errors
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Randomize' 
AND

Use of unassigned local variable 'randomPlanet'

Comment: What errors does it give you?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Randomize' 

AND 

Use of unassigned local variable 'randomPlanet'

Comment: It's fixed, I still don't know what was wrong, but I just extended the code by adding Materials and now it's working

Comment: Oh, well at least it works haha.

Comment: Thanks for the help though!